# Access to ApplicacionData using Anguilla Javascript

Tags: cme

I'm trying to develop an extension which allows me to get the applicacion data into the Content Manager. After reading a lot, i choose use Anguilla Framework to do that using a WFC, like you said above.
I have written the first code lines in the .svc, lines of example to probe the connection, but i still get an error:

*WCFAppData is not defined*

Could you help me please? I post the code/configuration here:

**JS file which call my svc:**

```
var onSuccess = this.getDelegate(this._handleUserInfo);
var onFailure = null;
var context = null;

WCFAppData.Services.Example.GetData(1, onSuccess, onFailure, context, false);
```

**Extension Config file**

[image: Extension config file]

**This is the folder structure:**
[image: Folder structure]

The svc code:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class Example : IExample
{
    public Example()
    {
        /*_EndpointName = "netTcp_2013";
        initalizeCoreService(_EndpointName);*/
    }

    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    /*private void initalizeCoreService(string _EndpointName)
    {
        _client = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient(_EndpointName);
    }*/

    public string DoWork(string value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

Could you help me? Its possible that the problem comes from another place? Do you think is something wrong or any lack of configuration?

Also I put the WCFAppData.dll in the path *C:\Tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\bin*

Thanks in advance!!